# Invalid ELF header Node js with couchbase db

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, couchbase

I've seen a handful of posts about this issue but the results all seem to be specific to the users configuration. I'm using couchbase db with a express js server. When I run the code locally (windows) it works fine. The database it self is hosted on a linux server. When I deploy the code to our testing environment    ( linux ), I'm getting this error when I try to run "node server.js":

```
/var/www/html/BTRnode/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw 8
Error: /var/www/html/BTRnode/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node: invalid ELF header
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:364:17)
    at ....
```

I'm completely lost on what to do in this situation. As mentioned before, it seemed to me like all the fixes in other peoples situation was some system configuration. I'm not sure what to post here to help you see any configuration that might help, but I can sure add it if needed. Also if there be a more general solution or error that I'm committing that'd be helpful to know to.

**Question**: What do I need to do to get this to run?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "invalid ELF header" error happens when you compile modules on one architecture and then try to run them on another. I'm guessing you're copying your entire project folder over, rather than installing the architecture-specific node modules on the testing environment. Make sure your package.json file is configured correctly, delete (or better yet, don't copy) your node_modules folder, and then run `npm install` on the target environment. This will pull and compile that modules for the particular environment.

Here is the documentation page about configuring and using your package.json: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

Comment: I was able to derive this answer from the other posts, but its good to have a solid "yes your assumption is correct" affirmation. Thanks.

Comment: Follow up question: I had originally copied over all the files as was mentioned, but the only one that's had issues is the node couchbase module. Is there a reason for that? IE what is it about the other modules that makes it so they don't care being copied and pasted over OR what is it about the couchbase that makes it so it doesn't like being copied and pasted over?

Comment: Many node modules are purely JavaScript and don't have compiled native components. The Couchbase module relies on libcouchbase and has a native wrapper for it that gets compiled as part of the installation.