# Not able to load Node JS function in AWS Lambda using Serverless Couchbase Lounge - getting invalid ELF header error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, couchbase, serverless

The platform architecture: Serverless AWS Lambda using Couchbase as database and connect using Lounge library.
It works fine when we tried serverless local invoke but upon deploying to AWS Lambda, getting the below error:

```
Error: /var/task/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node: invalid ELF header
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at bindings (/var/task/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:84:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:213:36)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

The closer thing i came across is this: [Invalid ELF header Node js with couchbase db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822326/invalid-elf-header-node-js-with-couchbase-db)

but not sure how to install platform specific in aws lambda. I ruled out the webpack and package dependecies.

Version:
node: 8.10.0
npm: 6.4.1
npm package couchbase: 2.6.4
npm lounge: 0.26.0

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase and CouchDB are NOT the same database, Couchbase's Database is called "Couchbase Server". So, in summary you are trying to connect in a database using the driver of the other.

In this framework it explicitly says CouchDB
https://github.com/mikeyk/couchdb-lounge

Comment: That seems like problem #2, but problem #1 is `invalid ELF header` -- the binaries in the module have been compiled for a platform other than the one backing the Lambda runtime environment.

Comment: Updated to Couchbase.