# Invalid ELF header Node js with couchbase db in AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, couchbase

The platform architecture: Serverless AWS Lambda using Couchbase as database. It works fine when we tried serverless local invoke but upon deploying to AWS Lambda, getting the below error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node: invalid ELF header",
    "stack": [
        "Error: /var/task/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node: invalid ELF header",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)",
        "    at bindings (/var/task/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:214:36)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)"
    ]
}
```

The closer thing i came across is this:[Invalid ELF header Node js with couchbase db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822326/invalid-elf-header-node-js-with-couchbase-db)

but not sure how to install platform specific in aws lambda. I ruled out the webpack and package dependecies.

Comment: Hi, try to see the version of couchbase installed locally vs on AWS server and be sure that it's exactly the same environment on both
You can also try to delete `node_modules` and reinstall everything with npm or yarn

Comment: Thanks,I cannot install nodemodules in lambda.
Its working locally perfectly fine.

Comment: is your lamba env 32 or 64 bits ? what's the specification env needed for couchbase ?
It's this or you have a shared node module somewhere incompatibility
Do you use yarn or npm ?

Comment: Its 64bit.I am using npm.